# Trigger event on resize but not on changing orientation

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, resize, orientation

```
<input type="button" value="button">    
<nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">abcd</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

The above is my html for my menu. I'm showing this as a pulldown menu, on clicking my button in mobile mode.

now i'm showing the same menu as a horizontal menu, `floating` the `li` to left; but this menu should always show up in desktop mode.And should be defaultly hidden in mobile mode.

to achieve this i've used the following code

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('nav').show();
  }else{
     $('nav').hide();
   }
});


$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
   $('nav').slideToggle();
});
```

now if i open menu in mobile device and change orientation, resize event is being triggered and the menu is disappearing, which should not happen. What can i do to avoid this!?!

Answer (score 0):

oh i got this..... `nav{display:block !important;}` in desktop mode, `nav{display:none;}` and removed resize function.

removed the below code from my code. and this worked perfectly.

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
  if($(window).width() > 992){
    $('nav').show();
  }else{
     $('nav').hide();
   }
});
```